# Object with private constructor and a static container (map) of itself?

Tags: c++, constructor, static, private, encapsulation

I'd like to have an object, `HIDDevice` which maintains a static `std::map` of itself. However, the class below results in compilation errors when the constructors and destructors are made private as shown below:

```
class HIDDevice
{
public:
    static HIDDevice* getDevice(unsigned short vendorID, unsigned short productID);

    int writeData(const unsigned char *data, int length);
    int readData(unsigned char *data, int length);

private:
    static std::map<std::string, HIDDevice> m_hidDevices;
    static bool isInitialized;
    static void initHIDAPI();


    HIDDevice(){};
    HIDDevice(unsigned short vendorID, unsigned short productID, std::string serialNumber = "");
    HIDDevice(std::string path);
    ~HIDDevice();

};
```

**EDIT**

Error Messages are as follows:

```
error C2248: 'HIDDevice::HIDDevice' : cannot access private member declared in class 'HIDDevice'
```

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. Although your error seems to be very obvious, and quite common, it cannot be confirmed without a [mcve].

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to put your content quality up

Comment: Imho your question is good and interesting, but copy-paste the compiler error message *fast* to satisfy everybody to avoid the reopening round.

Comment: In Standard C++ you can't have a class contain a map of itself (static or not).  An alternative would be to make the `map` a static variable in the `.cpp` file implementing this class

Comment: @peterh Yeah, I don't really see an issue with it either; especially since the header is what's causing the problem, not the implementation.Nonetheless, I was sleeping when it was put on hold. oh well

Comment: @M.M Yep, that did it, thanks. I changed my definition of `m_hidDevices` to `static std::map<std::string, HIDDevice*> m_hidDevices;` in the CPP file

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` doesn't get special access to private members of your class just because it happens to have a static member of type `std::map<something>`.

You cannot just declare `std::map` as a friend because there's no guarantee that constructors and destructors are actually called by members of `std::map`. This task may well be delegated to an internal implementation class or standalone functions.

Even if you manage somehow to make necessary friends it won't do you much good, as anyone then can declare the same kind of `std::map` and create objects of your class in their own map.

I suggest just making the constructors and destructors public.